# I am running out of 25gb ram on google colab

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

This is my code below I am making a multilabel classification model using 8000 x-ray images can someone here help me this is my code below most of the ram is used while loading the images itself and only 10 epochs are able to run.
Can someone tell me what changes do I need to make to this code for it to run and generate the model.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments

# initialize the initial learning rate, number of epochs to train for,
# and batch size
INIT_LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 40
BS = 66

# grab the list of images in our dataset directory, then initialize
# the list of data (i.e., images) and class images
print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images('/content/drive/My Drive/testset/'))
data = []
labels = []

# loop over the image paths
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # extract the class label from the filename
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

    # load the image, swap color channels, and resize it to be a fixed
    # 224x224 pixels while ignoring aspect ratio
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))

    # update the data and labels lists, respectively
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(label)

# convert the data and labels to NumPy arrays while scaling the pixel
# intensities to the range [0, 255]
data = np.array(data) / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

# perform one-hot encoding on the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 80% of
# the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
    test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

# initialize the training data augmentation object
trainAug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=15,
    fill_mode="nearest")

# load the VGG16 network, ensuring the head FC layer sets are left
# off
baseModel = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
    input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))

# construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the
# the base model
headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(64, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(headModel)

# place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become
# the actual model we will train)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

# loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
# *not* be updated during the first training process
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile our model
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the head of the network
print("[INFO] training head...")
H = model.fit(
    trainAug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)

# make predictions on the testing set
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predIdxs = model.predict(testX, batch_size=BS)

# for each image in the testing set we need to find the index of the
# label with corresponding largest predicted probability
predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)

# show a nicely formatted classification report
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1), predIdxs,
    target_names=lb.classes_))

# compute the confusion matrix and and use it to derive the raw
# accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity
cm = confusion_matrix(testY.argmax(axis=1), predIdxs)
total = sum(sum(cm))
acc = (cm[0, 0] + cm[1, 1]) / total
sensitivity = cm[0, 0] / (cm[0, 0] + cm[0, 1])
specificity = cm[1, 1] / (cm[1, 0] + cm[1, 1])

# show the confusion matrix, accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity
print(cm)
print("acc: {:.4f}".format(acc))
print("sensitivity: {:.4f}".format(sensitivity))
print("specificity: {:.4f}".format(specificity))

# plot the training loss and accuracy
N = EPOCHS
plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["accuracy"], label="train_acc",color='green')
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_accuracy"], label="val_acc")
plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy on COVID-19 Dataset")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.savefig('/content/drive/My Drive/setcovid/plot2.png')

# serialize the model to disk
print("[INFO] saving COVID-19 detector model...")
model.save('/content/drive/My Drive/setcovid/model2',save_format="h5" )
```

Comment: How much memory does your system have? Your `data` list is going to be about ~1.6 gigabytes which is not terribly large for some systems but unnecessary overhead. The correct approach here should be to wrap the images in a dataset which is more of a tensor streamer of sorts. This keeps one batch of tensors resident.

You can also try dropping your batch size and see how that changes things. 

Without knowing what your system is, this is a hard one to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate **TFRecords** from this data, store them into your drive and then **feed them into your model through batches** instead of directly loading them to memory. I would recommend the **Hvass Laboratories** YouTube channel, tensorflow tutorials playlist, tutorial number 18, **TFRecords and Dataset API** and the Dataset api tensorflow's official documentation.

Comment: I still wasn't able to figure it out can someone help me out with it.

Comment: Did you tried training with a smaller amount of images like 1 or 2k? you could verify if doing that reduces the amount of ram used and if so, you could instead input images to the model through batches

Comment: I could like i reduced the data size and it worked I have made batches but i dont why it isnt working could you help me ?